# AddQuickFile (Shift+F2) not working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

After updating my VS 2022 last week to version 17.4.0 the add quick file is not working anymore.
I used to use Mads Kristensen extension but now, with this new version, the extension was replaced by a built-in feature and when I type shift+f2 the Add New Item dialog shows up, I type something like Test.cs or ITest.cs and just an empty file is created.
I've already tried uninstalling the extension but it didn't work either.
Does anybody with the same problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem continues but for those that use Mads Kristensen Add New File extension, there is a way around it.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and remove the shortcut for AddQuickFile.
After that find NewEmptyFile (the full name is ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Project.Add.NewEmptyFile) and assign the SHIFT+F2 shortcut to it.
At least while the VS2022 doesn't work well, we can continue to use the extension.